# How to set the height of a UIPopoverPresentationController to be the same as your UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I'm using a UIPopoverPresentationController on my app to show a popover on my iPhone (with UIModalPresentationNone). I want the size to be dynamic with the height of the UITableView, but i can't find out how to do that. The size of the popover is the same on every device.

[image]
[image]

Comment: If the rowHeight is same for all the rows than take one minimum count variable to fix how many rows you want to display at a time and set tableview height based on that.if the item count is less than minimum count than change the table view frame based on count. height=count*rowHeight;

Comment: I know that, but I don't know where in the code I need to set the height of the popover.

Comment: tableView's viewControllerObj.contentSizeForViewInPopover=CGSizeMake(widht,height);

Comment: tableViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(width,height)

Answer (score 5):

In the class, that you present in popover add a code:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, tableView.contentSize.height);
}
```