# UIPopoverPresentationController showing as full-window modal popup

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a project for which I'm using a UIPopoverPresentationController, which I want to show as a popover for both iPhone and iPad. Even in a standalone project with just a blank Storyboard with a single UIButton, the following code keeps resulting in a full-screen modal popup instead. I've seen a question similar to this asked before on SO multiple times, but everyone seems to solve it by returning .None for adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController, but even including that isn't fixing it for me. I have a single ViewController with the following code--what am I missing?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var thatButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func presentPopoverController(sender: UIButton) {
    let popVC = UIViewController() //(nibName: "CameraPopover", bundle: nil)
    popVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    popVC.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    popVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    popVC.view.layer.borderWidth = 5
    popVC.view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor

    self.presentViewController(popVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    let popController = popVC.popoverPresentationController
    popController!.delegate = self
}

func prepareForPopoverPresentation(popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) {
    popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = .Down
    popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.thatButton
    popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = self.thatButton.frame
}

func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .None
}

func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .None
}

}
```

Comment: It will always be a modal on iPhones in portrait and I think only a popover on a 6+ in landscape (I'm a little foggy on that one at the moment).

Comment: I've seen screenshots of it as a popover on the iPhone before, such as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060801/how-to-set-the-height-of-a-uipopoverpresentationcontroller-to-be-the-same-as-you

Comment: Is your app set to Universal?

Comment: My basic test app was set to iPhone, but changing it to Universal didn't change the behavior in the iPhone (6+) simulator.

Comment: Interestingly, if I run this code in the simulator and hit thatButton, the popover shows as a full-screen modal. If I rotate the simulator to landscape, it shows up as a popover, and then when I rotate the simulator back to portrait, it remains as a popover. Is the full-screen modal behavior upon initial presentation a bug in iOS?